# Converting dash's(plotly) react functional component into class component

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly-dash

I just learned about the dash's [Create your own components](https://dash.plot.ly/react-for-python-developers) . I'm also new in react. I generally prefer to write component in react in **class**. I created a react file where I dumped the source code of [dash html component](https://github.com/plotly/dash-html-components/blob/master/src/components/Div.react.js) . The ***Div*** component is written in function. I want to convert this ***Div*** component into class. Here what i am doing -

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import {omit} from 'ramda';

class Div extends Component{

   render(){
     const props = this.props;
     const dataAttributes = {};
     if(props.loading_state && props.loading_state.is_loading) {
          dataAttributes['data-dash-is-loading'] = true;
     }

     return (
        <div id = "scroll-div" className="scroll-bar"
            onClick={() => props.setProps({
                n_clicks: props.n_clicks + 1,
                n_clicks_timestamp: Date.now()
            })}
           {...omit(['n_clicks', 'n_clicks_timestamp', 'loading_state', 'setProps'], props)}
        {...dataAttributes}
        >
           {props.children}

        </div>
    );
  }
};
Div.defaultProps = {
  n_clicks: 0,
  n_clicks_timestamp: -1,
};

Div.propTypes = {
     .......
};

export default Div;
```

But this conversion that i made into class is not working. What am I doing wrong? What will be the correct converion of the ***Div*** component into class?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should import :-

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
```

Or in the you can modify your class declaration as :-

```
class Div extends React.Component{}
```

Comment: Please comment under Code of Conduct. Please reformat your post, by formatting code as code. Thank you!